# Least Squares Problem (compute and plot fit using matlab)

Tags: matrices, matlab, least-squares, pseudoinverse

I have the following data for a least squares problem:
$$x: 0 , 1 , 3,  5 , 7,  9 , 12$$
$$y: 10 ,12, 18 ,15, 20, 25, 36$$

I have already found the normal equations and the pseudoinverse for the problem. 
my question is, how can I compute and plot the resulting fit for this problem using matlab?

Comment: Are you looking for the interpolating line $y = mx + q$, right?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm looking for!

Comment: I've never used matlab, so I'm not sure where to start!

Answer (score 1):

This is a forum about mathematics, not Matlab. I will try to give you a 
mathematical answer and the relative code to solve this problem with Matlab.

---

First of all, we need to define your problem in a matricia fashion.

The equation $y = mx+ q$ contains two parameters: $m$ and $q$. Then, I can write the previous equation in a matricial form:

$$y = [x ~~~ 1]\left[\begin{array}{c}m\\q\end{array}\right].$$

Since you have a lot of $x$s and $ys$, then:

$$\left[\begin{array}{c}10\\12\\18\\\ldots\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc}0 ~ 1\\1 ~ 1\\ 3  ~ 1 \\ \ldots\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}m\\q\end{array}\right].$$

Let's pose

$$U = \left[\begin{array}{cc}0 ~ 1\\1 ~ 1\\ 3  ~ 1 \\ \ldots\end{array}\right] ~\text{and}~ \theta = \left[\begin{array}{c}m\\q\end{array}\right].$$

Then, the problem is:
$$y = U \theta$$ and the solution is given by calculating the pseudoinverse of $U$, that is:

$$\hat{\theta} = U^{\#}y = (U^\top U)^{-1} U^\top y.$$

---

**Matlab code**

1) If $x$ and $y$ are column vector, go to step 3.

2) If $x$ and $y$ are row vector, then transform them to column vector as follows:

```
x = x(:);
y = y(:);
```

3) Build up the matrix $U$:

```
U = [x ones(7,1)];
```

where $7$ is the number of elements of $x$.

4) Evaluate the pseudoinverse $U^{\#}$ of U:

```
Usharp = pinv(U);
```

5) Finally, evaluate your results:

```
theta = Usharp*y;
m = theta(1);
q = theta(2);
```

The first element of theta is $m$, while the second is $q$.

6) To plot the data and the estimated line, use the following:

```
scatter(x, y);
hold on;
plot(x, m*x+q, 'r');
```

7) The fitting error can be obtained as follows:

```
fitErr = norm(y-(m*x+q))^2/7`
```

Comment: Although it's useful here to show all the steps (and I'm guessing that's why you did this), in practice it's better to bring 4-5 together and just solve `theta=U\y` rather than computing the pseudo inverse http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/

Comment: @tibL how do you insert code using monospace character? I'm curious!

Comment: using two backticks: ` (yourcode) then another one to close

Comment: @tibL thanks a lot!

Comment: I've also edited your code in your answer (just use four whitespaces in front of each code line)

Comment: @tibL sorry, I was editing it meanwhile...ops...

Comment: @tibL thanks a lot again, I've learned a new useful stuff today!

Comment: @Mowglin if the answer was helpful, please accept if. Press the uparrow and check mark on the right of the answer.